# Use the value resolved by async function in material UI Table Row / Table Cell

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, material-ui, tablerow

I have a table that is calling and passing some data through the `cells` prop of a MUI TableRow.

Some of the data that I need is exposed and consumable immediately from what is being passed in the `cells` prop array; in order to find other data that I would like (the name of a show) I need to make a call to an async function using that data (I need to make a call to get a show name from within a table using just the exposed showId).

Heres what I mean

```
<TableBody>
  {pushNotifications?.items.map(
    (pushNotification: IPushNotificationDTO) => {
      const {
        id,
        showId,
      notification: { title },
        audienceType,
        createdAt,
        sendAt,
      } = pushNotification;

      return (
        <TableRowComponent
          cells={[
            //this is the async call
            getShowName(showId),
            title,
            formatPushNotificationAudience(audienceType),
            new Date(createdAt),
            new Date(sendAt),
          ]}
          isSelected={selectedRow === pushNotification.id}
          onSelect={setSelectedRow}
          redirectTo={APP_DASHBOARD_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_PAST_PATH(
            pushNotification.id
          )}
          key={pushNotification.id}
          id={id}
        />
      );
    }
  )}
</TableBody>
```

And the function itself

```
const getShowName = async (showId?: string) => {
    const response = await getShow(showId);
    //logs expected data, a string name, or undefined
    console.log("logging response in getShowName ",response.name)
    return response.name
  };
```

The code compiles, but I get the error `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

How can I access the data I need using an async call to a function that accepts an `id` I only have within the table?

Thanks!

Comment: not exactly sure about this but I assume async function returning promise. try 'const response = await getShow(showId); this.setState({name: response.name });' in componentDidMount and then try to send 'name' in cells.

Comment: state is being managed with redux, so a setState({}) is not an option in this context